# Persisting/saving a JPA entity's relationships before that entity itself

Tags: java, jpa, spring-mvc

I have a `@OneToMany` JPA association with an instance of `Curriculum` having several instances of `WorkExperience`.

The  `Curriculum` JPA entity:

```
@Entity
public class Curriculum {
    ...
    @OneToMany
    private Set<WorkExperience> workExperiences;
    ...
```

The `WorkExperience` JPA entity:

```
@Entity
public class WorkExperience {
...
```

I originally wanted to persist the Curriculum together with its WorkExperiences in one entityManager call of the persist method.

However, given how I designed the flow of actions of the web UI, I am now wondering whether another scenario might not be possible i.e. to:

- persist the WorkExperiences to db first and then when the user has filled in the main Curriculum entity details, to :
- set the existing WorkExperience instances (already in db) to the Curriculum instance (not in db yet) and
- persist the whole object graph: Curriculum with its WorkExperiences.

Does that make sense? I thought of several cons, e.g. what happens if the user chooses not to persist the Curriculum instance? How do I clean up the dangling lines in the WorkExperience table?

Are there alternatives or better patterns? For instance would that be a good idea to pre-save the curriculum instance before the user validates the form?

Answer (score 2):

I would define a cascade on the `Curriculum`, since `WorkExperience` seems to be a dependent entity.

Then work with new/detached entities in the UI/Controllers until the user decides to submit the (last) form. Then persist the `Curriculum` and the related `WorkExperience` entities will be persisted as well during the same transaction commit.

```
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<WorkExperience> workExperiences;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Kostja. OK, but where do I store the detached instances of WorkExperience before the Curriculum is finally saved?

Comment: @balteo Put them in the `Set` inside the detached Curriculum entity, so the persisting will be cascaded. I am not familiar with Spring MVC, but I assume that you have a controller for your view that is instantiated and has a method to handle form submits. This controller is where I would store the Curriculum entity before persisting. For views where users create new entities, I usually create an empty entity during the instantiation of the controller, operate on it and then persist it after a successful submit.

Comment: Uhmm. Spring MVC controllers are singletons. It is not a good idea to put state in a Singleton. I thought about using the session for storage but it's not a very good idea either...

Comment: @balteo Singletons? That makes the issue a bit more complicated. I think that using session-scoped beans is not a bad idea. You could inject a session-scoped bean containing the Curriculum like explained [**here**](http://richardchesterwood.blogspot.de/2011/03/using-sessions-in-spring-mvc-including.html). I am not a good advisor on Spring details though - my main expertise is using JPA (with JSF, where controllers are often stateful) and I thought your question was mainly about JPA. Sorry if my answer is being less than helpful.

Comment: I am not keen on storing data in the session. Maybe a solution based upon pre-saving the Curriculum instance through ajax would be better.

Comment: @balteo You could save a new Curriculum instance and refetch, update and merge it each time a new WorkExperience is added. However this implies that the application is effectively stateful. By persisting on each change you simply push the state into the DB. This can have an undesired performance impact, so if possible I would prefer to keep the state inside the application, especially if the state is subject to frequent changes. I am not sure if there is a intermediate scope in Spring, like the View or Conversation scopes in JSF/CDI. If there is, it would be clearly preferrable to the session.